# Authentication with graphical interface

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, gtkmm

Basically i'm trying to implement a Graphic interface with Gtkmm to one of my programs created with C++.

And i don't know if I can make a window appear to be able to put the password of sudo.

I think that could be a command in order to get that but i have read that Gksu has been removed in the latest versions of Ubuntu, for example.

Example of the window that i want.

[image]

Comment: the command for which i need the sudo passwd is a Rm -rf. this is not so important but I clarify in case the doubts

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reinvent `gksudo`.

Comment: But gksudo is not working on the last versions of ubuntu for example isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But a search for the package should lead back to its source code. With source code in hand you should have a lot of inspiration at your fingertips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with: pkexec

`system(("pkexec rm -rf "+pathi+"/'"+games[k]+"'").c_str());`

More information about commands as sudo in:

> [That post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root/3064#3064)